# Take object color of underlying Emitter

Tags: texturing, particles, color

What to setup if the emitter should take the objects based on the color where it comes out?

Sample: Icosphere should take the color of where it emits on cube.

[image]

There is [one solution for images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38207/particle-color-based-on-where-the-particle-is-emitted). How to setup this with color ramp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a similar way as described in the linked answer.

Just copy your material node setup from the cube to the icosphere, change the coordinate type from *Generated* to *Object* and choose the cube object from the list.

[image: Object coordinates particle]