# How to color particles based on the texture of the object from which they are emitted, using the "grid" emission setting?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I am using Blender's particle system to try to voxelize my mesh. I'd like to color the voxels based on the diffuse color of the textured mesh at the closest location to each voxel. This is an image that shows what I'm trying to do:

[image]

[This Stack Exchange post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38207/particle-color-based-on-where-the-particle-is-emitted) explains how to color emitted particles based on the mesh from which they are emitted. The technique uses the "jittered" emission setting:

[image]

Using the technique in the post I linked to, here is what I get with "jittered" selected. You can see that the emitted cubes correctly match the color of the mesh:

[image]

When I change the emission setting to "grid", the cubes no longer match the color of the object:

[image]

I'd like to use the "grid" emission setting for voxelization, but can't figure out how to get the color of the emitted particles to correctly match the color of the mesh.

This is what my shader nodes look like for the cube which I am using as the dupli object:

[image]

I'd appreciate any help with this! Please let me know if there's something I can clarify.

Comment: It seems that particles UV (with the grid option) are calculated from the vertices bounding box of the mesh (starting from the min vertex). So not related to the positions of the mesh faces

Comment: are you planning to animate this? I can only see the grid option when you set the particle system to emission. But for a character in motion you'll have to set it to hair, otherwise the particles will detach from the surface right after emission happened. This would force you to take a different approach anyways.

Comment: Do you need the cubes to be monocolor or can they inherit from all the below colors ?

Comment: I have a possible solution for this, just wonder if you expect all blocks as one piece or individual objects.

Comment: @Miles - Can you post your original Blend File?

Comment: Interesting how that Luigi's L is the wrong way around.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38207/particle-color-based-on-where-the-particle-is-emitted/

Comment: I'm doing something similar except it's a tree trunk and instead of cubes I'm trying to match the branch particles to that trunk however the shader node above uses an image texture. My material doesn't use an image texture. So how will it work for me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A bit 'complicated' solution, as it seems that the particles UV are relative to the mesh boundings when the '*grid*' option is set, not to the parent UV map (so I don't think this is possible to tune the nodes to obtain the wanted result, if you want to use particles) :

[image]

To do it :

- Tune your particle system to obtain the grid dimensions you need
- Apply the particle system, by clicking convert here :

[image]

- You will obtain a duplicate of the cubes (on the right here) :

[image]

- This cubes are dupli from the same object, so make them single user, by selecting them all and use the "*make single user/object & data*' menu, like below, and confirm '*selected objects*'

[image]

- Now join them all in order to have 1 mesh from them. As they are still all selected use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
- Enter edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Them select all the vertices and unwrap <kbd>U</kbd> using the '*smart UV project*' mode. It will give you some kind of UV grid like in the right part of the picture below :

[image]

Now we will make a bake from the original to the cube shape. This bake wont work directly because the proximity between the cubes and the original mesh is not good.
So, to overpass that :

- Add a shrinkwrap modifier to the cubes and set your original mesh as target object :

[image]

Now we can bake :

- 1 : Add a material to your cube mesh
- 2 : Add a image texture with a newly created texture. Keep this node active.
- 3 : Select your original mesh <kbd>RMB</kbd> then the cube mesh with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>
- 4 : Go to the bake part of the render panel and check '*selected to active*'
- 5 : click '*bake*'

[image]

- Disable or remove the shrinkwrap modifier we set above
- Using the baked texture, you obtain this below, with several colors on each cube :

[image]

If you need one color per cube, (**edit : one color per face !**)

- Go to the UV editor
- Select all your UVs
- Set pivot to individual origins
- Then scale to 0 <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

[image]

Doing that each cube UV is reduced to one point, and we obtain this :

[image]

If needed you can separate the cube in edit mode, using <kbd>P</kbd> then '*by loose parts*' (this may take some calculations...).
[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the help @lemon! The suggestion to scale the individual faces on the UV map is brilliant. Do you know if there is a way to obtain a single color per cube? Using your method, I get a single color per face, perhaps because smart UV project creates a UV island for each cube face.

Comment: @Miles, I will think about it (one color per cube) but no good ideas for now...

Comment: Smart part here imho is to use bake + shrinkwrap. The reason I didn't use grid particle is that it is hard to control the gap between cubes accurately to real zero. But of course it is more effective than using Animation Nodes addon if you don't care about that so much.

Comment: Smart part here imho is to use bake + shrinkwrap. The reason I didn't use grid particle is that it is hard to control the gap between cubes accurately to real zero. But of course it is more effective than using Animation Nodes addon if you don't care that so much.

Comment: Very nicely written and structured answer, +1

Comment: @LeonCheung, the solution is not perfect for two reasons : one color per face (and not per cube), normal problem during the bake (so that inner faces are partially black). In the other hand, the data transfer (your solution) works for that, but I did not succeed to avoid it to miss the map on a complex model (I mean by that, some of the UV are out of the original UV/texture)

Comment: There are some options for that operation for face mapping methods. Use the most suitable one.

Comment: @LeonCheung, I have tried some... each time, with the girafe, some UV were on the bad part of the texture. But I have not tried all possibilities

Comment: I know the data transfer method is not perfect anyway. Yesterday I've already tried to report the Grid particle problem as a bug [here](https://developer.blender.org/T48928), let's wish something good happen.

Comment: @LeonCheung, I think I have found the code in Blender that does that. Explicitly, the UV coords follow the bounding volume (certainly because of the invert option when gid is chosen). This is line 158 in particle_distribute.c in a function called distribute_grid (so a special case)

Comment: Really enjoyed reading this, great results and well explained.

Answer (score 13):

There might be something odd with the *Grid* distributed particle when working with *From Dupli* feature. Before it can be officially solved, you can consider another non-particle way:

1. Create an 3D array of cubes to cover the target object. Then group them for further convenience.

[image]

2. Get rid of all outter cubes around the target. You may have to do that with some scripting work, or with help of Animation Nodes addon like this:

[image]

3. Disable Animation Nodes addon. Select all visible objects, move them to another empty layer, then go back to the original layer, <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> to make all invisible cubes visible again, then delete them all. Finally you can move all other objects from another layer back to the current layer (or not):

[image]

4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> to join all cubes as one single mesh, then go to Edit Mode, switch Selection type to Face, and make sure Limit Selection button is toggled, then use selection tools to select all visible faces around the mesh:

[image]

5. After that, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> to select all linked cubes, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> to invert selection, then delete. This will remove all inner cubes.
6. Select all elements in the combined mesh, switch Pivot Point type to **Individual**, then <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> to make each block fairly small.

[image]

7. Back to Object Mode, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the target object. Keep all visible cubes selected, and the target object active (last selected), then find *Data Transfer* section in Toolshelf sidebar, click **Data** (or <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>) then **UVs**:
   [image]
8. Then select the joined mesh, switch to Edit Mode, select all elements then <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> to scale all blocks back to initial size.
9. Then set the material for joined mesh. Finally delete or move the target object away. Voilà:

[image]

If you want to separate the joined mesh into cubes again, select all elements in Edit Mode, then press <kbd>P</kbd> -> **By loose parts**. Then <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> to center origins for each cube.

---

And of course, you can use Remesh Modifier here, things goes quite similar but the result goes a bit different. It all depends on what kind of result you really want. (Mine strictly follows the Mario style you presented, which is, one single color per cube.)

Comment: UVed. Very nice use of animation nodes for modeling!

Answer (score 7):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but if you are going for a result like the top image with Louigie, you might want to consider not using a *Particle System*, but a *Remesh* modifier with the *Mode:* set to *Blocks* and *Remove Disconnected Pieces* disabled.

*Remesh modifier:*

[image]

*Without modifier:*

[image]

*With Modifier:*

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to make an object where each of the voxels is a separate cube, and AFAIK _Remesh_ with the _Blocks_ setting produces a single object that can't be separated.

Comment: It can be separated. Go in edit mode, press "p", then "separate by loose parts". Hope that helps.

Comment: @UncleSnail No, it cannot.  :)

Comment: Shady, I wanted to rework on this subject, and I do not succeed to keep the UV map using your approach. Do you know why ? I mean remesh looses the UV map

Comment: @Leon Cheung Oh, I'm sorry, you have to convert before you can separate. :P