# Making a model out of cubes, can't fix overlap

Tags: modeling

I'm working with a Minecraft model, and am using hand places cubes as extrusions for the hair of the character, as I am unsure of how to extrude pixel sized "blocks" from the mesh. The problem I have arises with a tiny bit of overlap with some of the cubes, causing a weird look. Is there a way to fix this overlap without having to go back and hand scale/rearrange the cubes, or an easier way to achieve this extrusion? The cube's aren't perfectly aligned, as I did it all by hand. Is there possibly an easier way to align them?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are the cubes perfectly aligned? If so that may make solving the problem easier.

Comment: I think you could use another approach, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58200/how-to-color-particles-based-on-the-texture-of-the-object-from-which-they-are-em

Comment: @Bradman175 They aren't. Is there a way to make a grid they can snap to or something like that? How else can I align them perfectly if I'm doing it by hand?