# How to make object particles (hair) copy the color of parent object?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, particles, eevee-render-engine

So I have a bunch of grass *(particles)* that I want to have a gradient that then multiplies into the base color *(the base color is a texture image)* which I did figure out but I cant make the base color to be the texture image because the particles system is set to "render as object"
It only copies the color of the image texture when it is set to "render as path"
But i have to keep the particle system "render as object" because having the gradient is not possible with the particles set to path, as far as  I know

Here is my blend file: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2daf37697e823e88e916e4e53f396afe20220715135101/d5a76770e7c80fe9b1977b96086d7a9020220715135101/9f13da

Here are my node settings (1 is of the field) and (2 is of the grass blade)
[image: one]

[image: two]

So is it possible to have both the gradient and the image texture working?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38207/particle-color-based-on-where-the-particle-is-emitted https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58200/how-to-color-particles-based-on-the-texture-of-the-object-from-which-they-are-em

Comment: It only works on cycles, isn't working when I switch it to eevee