# How to texture particles to give the effect of a picture mosaic to a Sphere?

Tags: texturing, particles

I would like to create an effect of a Sphere with an image texture explodes to smaller spheres but with the same image texture.When the particles come together it should create the main Sphere.

The problem I am facing while using the *Texture Coordinate* node and *From Instancer* option, Its applying the color to the whole particle. I want the particle to have same image texture as main sphere but when the particles combine together, it should give the main sphere with texture.

[image]

Hope i explained it clearly. Please suggest me if there is any method to achieve this.

Comment: please add an image or link to an animation how it should look like, thx

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38207/particle-color-based-on-where-the-particle-is-emitted/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58200/how-to-color-particles-based-on-the-texture-of-the-object-from-which-they-are-em/

Comment: @Chris I added an image to show the idea.