# How do I match object material in ParticleSystem to material it's parented to?

Tags: materials, objects, shaders, particles

I was following this youtuber's video on how to make an anime style shader for my tree stem model but there're "three" different branch objects, "all" of which are part of the "same" collection that exist separately from it. The collection itself is also used in the "ParticleSystem" for said tree.

I tried recycling the same material I used on it for each of the branches unfortunately, they don't exactly match up. Now I could select "Make Instances Real" then "join" all the branches together with the tree stem model, so the materials will match seamlessly, however I want to keep the branches separated this way in case, I can edit them in the future.

Is there a way to do that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58200/how-to-color-particles-based-on-the-texture-of-the-object-from-which-they-are-em https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38207/particle-color-based-on-where-the-particle-is-emitted/