# How to make a Particle System follow a Cloth Simulation?

Tags: particles, physics, cloth-simulation

I've been looking all over the internet and can't seem to find an answer. I'm sorry if this is a really dumb question, but how do I make a **Particle System** follow a **Cloth**:

[image]

How do I make it so that the rainbow colored particles follow the rainbow colored cloth instead of staying in one spot?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Final:

[image: Final]

### Overview:

If you want to keep **Particles** over the **Cloth** surface you will need to turn off any **Particles Physics** simulation (choose **No**) and also to prevent **Particles** from rotating like crazy after collision you will need to set **Emitter Geometry** > **Normal** under **Velocity** tab to **0**, like so:

[image: settings]

### Edit:

You also need to pay attention to Modifier Stack as this is very important thing in many operation based on modifiers. You have got Cloth simulation as a last modifier so Blender first started Particle Systems and after them Cloth. So as a solution you will need to move the Cloth modifier above the Particle modifiers in the Stack:

[image: modifiers]

Comment: @quinnamations I also think that this will allow you to simplify your setup a bit: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38207/particle-color-based-on-where-the-particle-is-emitted