# Colorize Instances according to vertex color or UV map

Tags: python, scripting, uv, vertex-colors

I have a vertex colored model (1) and I'm using [Cells v1.2](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.4/Py/Scripts/Add/Cells_v1.2) to generate a hollow voxel model of my Object.(2)

I want to change the object color of every instance/voxel according to the underlying vertex color or UV map.
As shown in picture (4).

[image]

In [this stackexchange post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38207/particle-color-based-on-where-the-particle-is-emitted) the instance inherits the color from the emitting vertex. 
Tricky part is that in my model the instances/voxels don't line up with the underlying vertices of the original model. Seen in picture (3).

How do I find the nearest color for every instance?
The result should consist of separate objects with its own object color.
I want to export every individual color as an .stl file.