# Blender 2.8x - Particle Color based on actual color of emitter

Tags: particles, color

Looking for a way to set the color of each particle to the exact color from where it was emitted.

Trying to make a 2d image plane dissolve effect.

Checked this thread but its not doing what I am trying to achieve:
[Particle Color based on where the particle is emitted?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38207/particle-color-based-on-where-the-particle-is-emitted)

[image]

I'd like to get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Lumpengnom at https://blenderartists.org/ 
I found the solution!

Important steps are:

1.) Add a texture coordinate node, connect UV to vector and enable the "from Instance" check-mark.

2.) Use Cycles renderer, also for preview!, otherwhise you will not so the right result which is very irritating.

**Here is a quick video tutorial:
https://youtu.be/8W1J8hYjK9g**

[image]

Comment: Links can go down... Do you mind adding a few steps which actually solved your issue to this question?

Comment: This is really useful. I'm posting [an example .blend](https://blend-exchange.com/b/2wVk06gQ) just to make the details of the particle system settings and material nodes totally clear.