# Colouring a particle system based on the emitter (Blender 3.1.2)

Tags: particles, color, emission

I am quite new to blender but i have to get a task done and i am learning a ton of stuff as i go. So here is my problem:
i want to have a particle system on a plane thats devided x times on the Y and X axes so i can set it up in a non chaotic grid. To achive this I emit the particles from the vertices and render them as instance objects that are based on a uv sphere. the result is much to my liking but now I have to colorize it with stripes on certain areas.

I have tried to set up colorramps and shaders to control the color and the area thats effected. But I can use this setup just in a certain area of my particle system maybe just in half of it. the colorramp also doesn't work linear but more or les logarythmic. When I shift arround a second particle system with the same setup and material, the stripes kinda have some depency on the XY axes too. BTW I am working with Cycles.

Sadly I can`t provide any open files, but i can provide you a picture of my material set up.

So in total is there any way i can achive my desired effect of having a grid like particle system that is colored differntly in certain areas?

I Would be very happy if some one could help me out
[image: material shader set up]

Comment: Similar questions: 1) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166840/blender-2-8x-particle-color-based-on-actual-color-of-emitter -- 2) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203035/how-to-add-a-texture-to-the-emitter-surface-of-a-hair-particle-object-over-ridi

Comment: Thanks Blunder, but this solution might not work for me, I saw this post previously and in this example they are emitting the particles from the faces of the plane not the vertices. if you change this blender example to "emit from vertices" all particles turn to the color of the instants object. But I need to emit them from the vertices to achieve a nearly perfect grid effect

Comment: there is also the exact same question but the links provided as answers are not working anymore https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66929/inherit-color-on-hair-particles-emitted-from-vertices-cycles

Comment: With Geometry Nodes (GN), you can map the (face) colors of an image texture to vertex colors. Unfortunately, it seems not to work with the particle system (Blender 3.1). But you can also instance objects with GN. The drawback is that you need to realize the instances to color them. This can result in a lot of geometry in the viewport.

Comment: Hello Blunder, unfortunally I cant't realize the instances, because it would slow down my computer to the extend that i could not work with this blend anymore, but i guess this would be the right solution for some simpler geometry. Thanks a lot, I am going to try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q: How to colorise particles by emitter's texture when emitted from Vertices?**

Don't use *UV* but **Generated coordinates** with *From Instancer* enabled.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello vklidu, actually this did the trick!!! thanks a lot! Now I can paint the desired design with texture paint and thats pretty cool!
Right now I try to make it work with the gradient texture too. So far the instances show the texture of the instance object :/ Same setup just switching from image texture to gradient texture + ColorRamp and I am stuck again.
But thank you so far!

Comment: If the answer solved your issue consider mark answer as accepted. https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour if you have another issue that wasn't asked already on this site don't hesitate to ask a new Q. Good luck with your project (•‿•)