# Custom hair objects

Tags: objects, particles, hair, color

Hello i create to custom hair object. But custom strand doesn't affected root object color. How can i do that?

[image]

i want to blend custom object color and hair base color.

[image]

Dont look shape orientation. i need to mix color.

Comment: object random > color ramp works. But i need base object exact color. (Light blue area, light blue multiplied object, dark blue area dark blue multiplied object) 
   https://i.ibb.co/TRkCLgK/exact-color.jpg

Comment: Might this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38211/35559

Comment: Thank you robin. This is very usefull. i use this setup.