# Python for cutting faces from planes according to transparency

Tags: python

So, I have an image with an alpha channel imported as a plane. Id like to create a python script to cut the plane into faces which are transparent and opaque, and then delete the transparent faces..however, I have no idea where do to start, which modules to use....so, please help!

Comment: Hello ! This may be related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205539/generate-3d-mesh-from-2d-sprite/205548 Please add more information about the setup, what kind of image you're using ,etc :)

Comment: Hi! That was pointed in a similar direction, but not quite. I have an image, with some pixels having alpha 0. I import that image as a plane, and I'd like to have all the alpha0 pixels subtracted from the plane. So, for example, say I have a square image, with the top half having 0 alpha, and the bottom half having alpha1, Id like to run this image as a plane into a code, and get just the bottom half remaining in the mesh, which had alpha1.