# Fixed stream of particles that represent pride flag?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, particles

I've been wracking my brain on how to get a stream of particles to emit from a 5 face plane and have the texture that is on the faces. I tried using [Particle Color based on where the particle is emitted?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38207/particle-color-based-on-where-the-particle-is-emitted) this question to make it work but it just did not.

I'm looking to avoid having more than one emitter for the process.

Here is my file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/51xXL0g6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instance object, the icosphere, has two materials on it: "odd" and "Oddness". The first material slot gets automatically assigned to all faces. The second one you don't need on the icosphere, to remove it you can simply select it and click on the minus button to the right (note: you can only delete it like this in *Object Mode*).

[image: delete second material]

Now you need to modify the "odd" material a little bit to work properly: Delete the *Color Ramp* (if you want to use a color ramp instead of an image, see below), *Object Info* and *Mapping* nodes. In the *Texture Coordinate* node, remove the chosen object by clicking X next to the name and enable *From Instancer*.

[image: modify material]

And it works - although the effect will only be visible in *Rendered* view. The *Material View* uses *Eevee*, but this only works in *Cycles*.

[image: result]

By the way, if you want to get rid of using an image texture and simply distribute the colors with a *Color Ramp* you can do it like this:

In the plane material, plug the *UV* output of the *Texture Coordinate* node into a *Separate XYZ* node. Plug the Y output into a *Color Ramp* with the colors as before or which others you want. Do not select an object there and make sure *From Instancer* is disabled.

The icosphere gets the same material - either by using the plane's material and clicking on the small number next to the name to make a duplicate of it or adding a new material and building it like the first - but with a little difference: in the icosphere material, you enable *From Instancer*.

[image: plane material]

[image: icosphere material]

Comment: Thank you for explaining it with such detail! It's working now!